# Could not get JDBC Connection - Connection Closing Issue

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

On production environment I got following error.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
```

When I connect through toad, it said ORA-12541 no listener error. The issue resolved after restart of linstener.

But the actual issue may be that lot of connections opened by the web application and it is not closing that. Following are my code and configuration.

I am using EcllipseLink, dbcp2 for connections

```
<persistence-unit name="persistance-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.company.model.Characteristic</class>
        ...
        <!--more classes -->

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

dbcp2 settings

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="200" />
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="60000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
        <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="10" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Connection Factory

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistance-unit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Transaction Management

Abstract GenericDao

```
public abstract class  GenericDao<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager

    private Class<T> type


    public GenericDao() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t
        type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]
    }

    @Override
    public T save(final T t) {
        this.entityManager.persist(t)
        return t
    }

    public def saveObj(def t) {
        try {
            this.entityManager.persist(t)
        }catch(e){
            log.info("Error occured: ", e)
        }
        return t
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final Object id) {
        this.entityManager.remove(this.entityManager.getReference(type, id))
    }

    @Override
    public T find(final Object id) {
        return (T) this.entityManager.find(type, id)
    }

    @Override
    public T update(final T t) {
        return this.entityManager.merge(t)    
    }

    @Override
    public def executeNamedQuery(String namedQueryName, Map<String, Object> queryParams)
    {
      List results = null
      try {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQueryName)
        if (queryParams) {
          addPrametersToQuery(query, queryParams)
        }
        results = query.getResultList()
      } catch (NoResultException e) {
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occured: ", e)
        throw e
      }
      return results
    }       
}
```

Dao component using that Generic Dao

```
@Component("characteristicDao")
class CharacteristicDao extends GenericDao<Characteristic> implements ICharacteristicDao {

    public def getCharacteristics(String name){
        log.info("Entering getCharacteristics")
        Characteristic characteristic = (PrmCharacteristic) executeQueryWithSingleResult("select b from Characteristic b where b.name=:name", [name:name])
        log.info("Exiting getCharacteristics")
        return characteristic
    }
}
```

I use CharacteristicDao component to interact with database. Similarly I have other dao also. I have just given one example.

I use @Transactional in service for the transaction. Any master can help me please what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems to be a network level error, which is confirmed by listener being down. If you suspect connection leak, then monitor established TCP connection count between app and DB and see if that grows steadily.

Comment: How can I check that, to be more precise ?

Comment: `netstat -pant | grep ESTA | grep db_port_number` arguments to netstat might vary based on your OS. Add -c to grep to get count.

Comment: There is no 'connection closing' here. Read the error message. There is a connection *creation* issue. Is the database server running? Have you specified the correct Ip:port?

Comment: yes, its production code. I just put the configuration here. Spring is injecting the EntityManager, will it not close the connection here?